# images/videos/mp3s on Network file system using php

Tags: php, ubuntu-10.04

I did some Google searches and can't seem to find what i want. I'm designing my web site to use MYSQL, PHP Web Servers. multiple web servers with load balancers and a MySql Custer for scaling is planed so far. But then i get to images/videos/mp3s. I need a file system multiple servers can read files from and write files to. So one web server can run the MySQL, Networked File System and Web Server, but as the site scales the site can be switched to multiple servers. Does anyone have any examples, tutorials or resources to help me on this? The site runs on Ubuntu Servers.  My original idea was to just store the images in MySQL(I know how to do that and have working examples) so all servers could read/write but other people told me thats a bad idea and i should use a file system(but don't want to use the local one, as i don't think it san scale for large sites).

Answer (score 1):

There are Three systems that come to mind - [Mogilefs](http://www.danga.com/mogilefs/), [Mongodb GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) and a cloud based storage solution.

MogileFS (OMG Files!) was developed for Livejournal and stores metadata in Mysql. It uses that to find the actual disk with the appropriate file and streams it out.

MongoDB GridFS is a lot newer, and probably easier to get going, certainly for a smaller system. It uses a new 'NoSql' database to store parts of files across its database, assembling as required. Searching around for information will find plenty of information.

Finally, you could simply avoid the whole issue and just upload images into [Amazon's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), or [Rackspace Cloudfiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/). I've done the latter before (though the site was already running inside Rackspace's system) and it's not very difficult, again with plenty of examples around.

For S3 there is also a command-line tool, [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) that can be set to sync (or, better) upload and then delete a directory full of files into an S3 'bucket'.

Answer (score 0):

First storing images/large files is not really possible with MySQL because of the maximum size limitation

To quote this answer [Choosing data type for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589143/choosing-data-type-for-mysql/5617109#5617109)

> MySQL is incapable of working with any data that is larger than max_allowed_packet (default: 1M) in size, unless you construct complicated and memory intense workarounds at the server side. This further restricts what can be done with TEXT/BLOB-like types, and generally makes the LARGETEXT/LARGEBLOB type useless in a default configuration.

Now for storage and upgrade compatibility why not just store them on an NAS or Raid system that you can continue to tack drives onto.  Then in your DB just store a path to the file. Much lest db intensive and allows for decent scalability.

Comment: Didn't think about looking for Network-attached storage. Was searching "Network File System Php" before i asked this question.